# Ruby sort array on condition in reverse order

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an array in descending order in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby)

I want to sort an array of elements based on some condition, except in reverse order. So basically whatever it would have done and then reversed.

So for example I have an array of strings and I want to sort it by decreasing string length

```
a = ["test", "test2", "s"]
a.sort_by!{|str| str.length}.reverse!
```

While this does the job...is there a way to specify the condition such that the sorting algorithm will do it in reverse?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The length is a number so you can simply negate it to reverse the order:

```
a.sort_by! { |s| -s.length }
```

If you're sorting on something that isn't easily negated then you can use `sort!` and manually reverse the comparison. For example, normally you'd do this:

```
# shortest to longest
a.sort! { |a,b| a.length <=> b.length }
```

but you can swap the order to reverse the sorting:

```
# longest to shortest
a.sort! { |a,b| b.length <=> a.length }
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good trick!

Comment: +1 for typing faster than me :P

Comment: Performance wise this is better (and more semantic if you ask me): `a.sort_by(&:length).reverse`

Answer (score 8):

The answer from @mu is too short is great, but only works for numbers. For the general case, you can resort to the `sort` method:

```
 irb> a = ["foo", "foobar", "test"]
  => ["foo", "foobar", "test"]
 irb> a.sort{|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}
 => ["foo", "test", "foobar"]
 irb> a.sort{|a,b| b.length <=> a.length}
 => ["foobar", "test", "foo"]
```

Comment: `sort_by(&:length).reverse` will be both more readable and faster.

Comment: I agree, but that wasn't the question.