# How to calculate median in a Rails app that uses SQLite3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to do a median calc in a Rails 4 app that uses the default SQLite3 database?

I've built the app already but would like to add a median function, and I see that the active_median gem only works with PostgreSQL for now:

https://github.com/ankane/active_median

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763965/how-can-i-calculate-the-median-of-values-in-sqlite

Comment: Do you want to calculate in memory or database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Median in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859120/calculating-median-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to calculate median

```
def median(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  len = sorted.length
  return (sorted[(len - 1) / 2] + sorted[len / 2]) / 2.0
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working with a  group of objects so I adjusted this as such:              def self.median(relation, column_name)
  array = []
  relation.select(column_name).each do |x|
   array << x.send(column_name)
  end
    sorted = array.sort
    len = sorted.length
    return (sorted[(len - 1) / 2] + sorted[len / 2]) / 2.0
 end