# Ruby: How do I go about iterating over files in a directory, ordered based on last edit time

Tags: ruby, directory

I'm iterating over the files in a given directory in ruby, ie:

```
Dir.each
```

I'd like to iterate over the files in sorted order - descending or ascending by last edit date. What's the shortest way to write code to do this, in ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will sort them in ascending order:

```
Dir['*'].sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f) }
```

if you want them in descending order, add `reverse!` which [seems to be the fastest method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby):

```
Dir['*'].sort_by{|f| File.mtime(f) }.reverse!
```

Comment: Or use `-File.mtime(f)`, which lets `sort_by` do the desired thing, rather than have it do an ascending sort and you `reverse` it afterwards to get the same result.

Comment: @theTinMan didn't you state in your own benchmark in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby" that `reverse!` is faster? ;-)