# Finding an object(s) within a hash with specific number using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create a method that takes a Hash and number as arguments and returns a new array of pet names by age.

```
my_family_pets_ages = {"Evi" => 6, "Hoobie" => 3, "George" => 12, "Bogart" => 4, "Poly" => 4,
  "Annabelle" => 0, "Ditto" => 3}
```

My I have two solutions to my problem:

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
    source.select {|k,v| v.include? thing_to_find}
end
my_hash_finding_method(my_family_pets_ages, 3)
```

or

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
    source.select {|k,v| v.has_value? thing_to_find}
end
my_hash_finding_method(my_family_pets_ages, 3)
```

When I run my program with IRB or the command line, I get:

```
my_solution.rb:15:in `block in my_hash_finding_method': 
undefined method `include?'for 6:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Why is `include?` an undefined method? It also says the same thing when I use `has_value?`
Could I be using an outdated version of Ruby? I'm on 2.0.0?

UPDATE:
This is the new solution I came up with, it seems to work.

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
    num_array = []
    source.each do |k,v|
      if v == thing_to_find
        num_array << k
      end
  end
    print num_array.sort
end
```

Comment: This smells like homework or an assignment of some sort. Version 2.0 is out of date as the current version of Ruby is 2.1.3, but I doubt that's the problem. (Though you should upgrade since 2.0 was buggy.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be a bit coy because this does sound like homework, but are you aware of what k and v stand for in that block?

The error message is a big hint.  It's telling you that you tried sending a message to something that isn't a Hash, and naturally it doesn't have the methods defined for Hashes.  You called `include?` on a Fixnum.

(Check [Ruby documentation for Hash select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) to know what's actually being put there if you want to know more.)

In short: inside the block, you're working with variables whose value get set by the Hash, not operating on the Hash itself.  You need to check based on those.

Answer (score 0):

The two methods in question don't exist by default, at least not for the objects you're using.

```
v.include?
```

would work if `v` was an Enumerable, like a hash or an array, but instead it's a numeric value because it's the value for that particular key, and doesn't have that method defined.

The same is true for `v.has_value?`. `v` is still the value for that particular key. `select` passes in the key and value as separate parameters if you use `|k,v|`. (In Ruby's way, they'd be a two-element array if you used a single variable.)

To help you learn to help yourself, Ruby includes the `ri` command available at the command-line. You can type in `ri has_value?` to see if that's implemented by any classes Ri knows about. Among other results is:

```
=== Implementation from Hash
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hsh.has_value?(value)    -> true or false

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns true if the given value is present for some key in hsh.

  h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
  h.has_value?(100)   #=> true
  h.has_value?(999)   #=> false
```

Along the same lines, for `include?`:

```
=== Implementation from Hash
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  hsh.include?(key)    -> true or false

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns true if the given key is present in hsh.

  h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
  h.has_key?("a")   #=> true
  h.has_key?("z")   #=> false
```

In either case, a numeric won't have those methods, which is where the error is coming from.

---

> Would something along the lines of this work?

```
  def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
    source.select {|k,v|
      if v == thing_to_find then return source[k] end
    }
  end
```

That's close, but `return` doesn't belong there and will result in only one value, even if there are multiple values existing. Consider this:

```
MY_FAMILY_PETS_AGES = {
  "Evi"       => 6,
  "Hoobie"    => 3,
  "George"    => 12,
  "Bogart"    => 4,
  "Poly"      => 4,
  "Annabelle" => 0,
  "Ditto"     => 3
}

def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select{ |k, v| v == thing_to_find }
end

my_hash_finding_method(MY_FAMILY_PETS_AGES, 3) # => {"Hoobie"=>3, "Ditto"=>3}
```

If you want to receive sorted results, well, why? `select` in current Rubies will return a hash, and hashes don't benefit from sorting since they're basically random-access objects, resulting in the ability to access values just as fast whether the hash is sorted or unsorted.

If you want to return a sorted array of key/value pairs, then this is one way to do it:

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select{ |k, v| v == thing_to_find }.sort_by{ |k, v| k }
end

my_hash_finding_method(MY_FAMILY_PETS_AGES, 3) # => [["Ditto", 3], ["Hoobie", 3]]
```

If you only want the names of the pets, instead of name and age, grab only the keys returned by `select`:

```
def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select{ |k, v| v == thing_to_find }.keys.sort
end

my_hash_finding_method(MY_FAMILY_PETS_AGES, 3) # => ["Ditto", "Hoobie"]
```

Notice that in the solution returning a hash from `select` I'm using [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), and a regular [`sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) in the last one. `sort` is fine for values like numerics and characters/strings which already have an established order, however it's inefficient when sorting using a block to access attributes inside the value passed in because it has to do a lot of redundant computing to determine how to order the incoming values. `sort_by` is an interesting algorithm commonly known as a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), which computes the value being sorted once per entry, remembers it, sorts by that value, then spits out the associated items afterward, in the correct order. That results in a very efficient sorting, which can greatly outperform a regular sort if the value being sorted isn't readily available.

I did benchmarks of the differences and how to quickly perform a descending sort in "[Sorting an array in descending order in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651028/128421)", so spend some time looking through the selected answer to that question.

Comment: @the_Tin_Man, I understand what you mean by calling .include? on an enumerable. Would something along the lines of this work? def my_hash_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
    source.select {|k,v| if v == thing_to_find then return source[k] end}
end

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to group by value the hash?

Then try:

```
pets.group_by{|k,v| v}
```

If you are trying to return just the array of items with a value:

```
pets.map { |k, v| v == value }
```