# Search for uppercased substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to take out the longest substring of uppercased characters. So out of the string:

```
"aaBBBBcBBdDDD"
```

I need to get `"BBBB"`.

Is there a convenient Ruby method for that or a regexp of some kind? I tried:

```
string.scan(/[[:upper:]]/)
```

and that's almost it, only it gives ALL capital characters, not the longest sequence.

Comment: That's not something regex can do. (At the very least, it's not something regex is designed to do.)

Comment: As @Rawing said, that's not what Regexp are for. Regular expressions are great at finding things that *look* like something, but they're terrible at finding something that is exactly something when presented with multiple choices, especially if there is any wiggle room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the string which has the maximum length only through regex. You need to use some built-in Ruby functions.

```
> m = "aaBBBBcBBdDDD".scan(/[[:upper:]]+/)
=> ["BBBB", "BB", "DDD"]
> vc = m.sort{|a,b| b.size <=> a.size}
=> ["BBBB", "DDD", "BB"]
> vc.delete_if{|a| a.size < vc.first.size}
=> ["BBBB"]
```

Comment: yep, `+` matches the previous token one or more times.

Comment: What if the string looks like this: `aaBBBBAABcBBdDDD` ? It would return `BBBBAAB`

Comment: yep , it returns `BBBBAAB`

Comment: I though sequences of *identical* uppercased characters should be returned.

Comment: Don't use `sort{|a,b| b.size <=> a.size}`. `sort_by` would be faster because it remembers the intermediate value, instead of `sort` having to compute the `size` of `a` and `b` each pass through the loop.

Comment: @theTinMan so you are suggesting `.sort_by{|a| -a.length}` Or `.sort_by(&:length).reverse)`? Or are you suggesting changing the last line to be `.delete_if{|a| a.length < vc.last.length}`. When benchmarking `sort_by` seems to be slower than `sort` in this case. Also in regards to this method right now it is determining the max on each loop through `delete_if` by referencing itself. I don't think this seems like the best approach.

Comment: I'd suggest reading "[Sorting an array in descending order in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby/2651028#2651028)".

Comment: Using `delete_if` isn't the best choice. I'd use `max_by` personally, but others MMV.

Answer (score 8):

Use regex to get an array of uppercase words, then use [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to find the longest:

```
"aaBBBBcBBdDDD".scan(/[[:upper:]]+/).max_by {|x| x.length}
# => "BBBB"
```

or simpler:

```
"aaBBBBcBBdDDD".scan(/[[:upper:]]+/).max_by(&:length)
# => "BBBB"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z]+)
```

Try this.Capture all the groups and the one with maximum length is your answer.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/11

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the expected result for more than 1 string of the same max length.

@AvinashRaj's answer will handle this while @YuHao's will not. If you want only 1 result I would suggest @YuHao's answer if you want all the results I would change @AvinashRaj's answer to something like this.

```
"aaBBBBcBBdDDDD".scan(/[[:upper:]]+/).tap do |a| 
   max_length = a.map(&:length).max
   a.delete_if{|x| x.length < max_length } 
end
#=> ["BBBB","DDDD"]
```

Comment: I don't think `tap` buys you anything here. It would be clearer, imo, to write: `a = "aaBBBBcBBdDDDD".scan(/[[:upper:]]+/); max_length = a.map(&:length).max; a.select { |s| s.size == max_length }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you for the response. There are probably a dozen more simply conceived options for this. I just don't see a need for multiple local variables that will not be utilized anywhere else. Benchmarking them shows not significant difference in performance either they are all within a 10% +/-