# How to sort a complex array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a proper way to sort by ascending or descending a complex array.

```
arr = [[100, 200, 300], [100, 250, 600], [50, 10, 1030]]
```

I would like to sort this array based on the target value [value, value, target_value]

I have my own way to do this but it seems ugly and slow.

Do we have a proper way to do this in ruby?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[100, 200, 300], [100, 250, 600], [50, 10, 1030]].sort_by{|x| x[2]}
```

Comment: you can append `.reverse`

Answer (score 4):

Or even shorter like this:

```
arr.sort_by(&:last)
```

If you need it in descend order:

```
arr.sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

To do the sorting and reversing in two steps seems laborious, but it is actually [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby/2651028#2651028) than the `sort {}` syntax.

Comment: Your answer works as well but how do i define ascend or descend?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it more explicitly:

```
arr.sort { |a, b| a[2] <=> b[2] }
```

For a descending sort, just reverse the order:

```
arr.sort { |a, b| b[2] <=> a[2] }
```