# How to sort an array of Integer and OpenStruct objects by a key of one of the OpenStruct Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I am just learning Ruby and started working with arrays. I have an array that looks like:

```
easyStats = [<SampleArray: @id=0, @stats=#<OpenStruct total_sessions_played=244, total_sessions_lost=124>>, 
             <SampleArray: @id=1, @stats=#<OpenStruct total_sessions_played=204, total_sessions_lost=129>>, 
             <SampleArray: @id=2, @stats=#<OpenStruct total_sessions_played=2, total_sessions_lost=4>>]
```

I can sort the array by the id (Integer) attribute as such:

```
easyStats.sort_by(&:id)
```

However, what I would like to do is sort the array by a key of the OpenStruct object, I have tried the following options with different errors:

```
easyStats.sort_by(&:stats)
```

> Error: comparison of OpenStruct with OpenStruct failed

```
easyStats.sort_by(&:stats[:total_sessions_played])
```

> Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

```
easyStats[:stats].sort_by(&:total_sessions_played)
```

> Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

I have seen solutions on how to sort an array of just one OpenStruct object and I think I understand it - [How to sort a ruby array by two conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856004/how-to-sort-a-ruby-array-by-two-conditions)

Could someone show me how to sort by any key of the OpenStruct object in this example (Array with Integer and OpenStruct objects)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort_by` method takes a block and uses the return value of that block as the key to sort by. In your case, you can access that value by doing:

```
easyStats.sort_by { |i| i.stats.total_sessions_played }
```

The `.sort_by(&:key)` code is really just shorthand for `.sort_by { |i| i.key }`. And you can only use it when the block consists of a single method called on the block argument.  You can read more about how and why it works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby).

Answer (score 2):

You should provide an actual block (since you are calling two methods on each item consecutively):

```
easyStats.sort_by{|x| x.stats.total_sessions_played}
```

So you can't really use a short notation with `&` here.