# Rails Sort Array By Two Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have an array called `surveys` that's made up of `Survey.all`

Each survey model has a `length` and `cost` columns.

What's the best way to sort an array first on `length`, and then on `cost`.

I basically want to do something similar to `Survey.all.order(length: :desc, cost: :asc)` but on the array after it's created.

Comment: The second answer to the duplicate in particular.

Comment: [**How to sort a ruby array by two conditions**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29856004/479863) would be another duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-):

```
surveys.sort_by { |survey| [survey.length, survey.cost] }
```

If you want to control asc vs desc, just multiply by -1:

```
surveys.sort_by { |survey| [-1 * survey.length, survey.cost] }
```

This should work for both regular array of objects or `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: will that work just on the `surveys` array? At this point in time I will just have access to the array rather than the Survey.all (i.e. I'm not actually using Survey.all to get my array of surveys but it was easier to type)

Comment: should work, try and let me know

Comment: can also use -survey.length for desc.