# Sorting array by more than one condition

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of points:

```
arr = [[2,0], [1,0], [2,1], [1,1]]
```

How would I sort the elements in descending and ascending orders by x first and then by y values of the similar x value?

```
max = [[2,1], [2,0], [1,1], [1,0]]
min = [[1,0], [1,1], [2,0], [2,1]]
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
min = arr.sort
# => [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
max = min.reverse
# => [[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

If performance is an issue rather than simplicity, then the following can be used.

```
min = arr.sort_by(&:itself)
```

Comment: [Benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby/2651028#2651028) show that sorting then using `reverse` is faster than using a negated value so +1.

Comment: In v2.2+ you can use [Array#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) to get `max`: `arr.max(arr.size) #=> [[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Is the order guaranteed in any document?

Comment: I was wondering about that too. Though I haven't seen anything, I'd expect it to duplicate `sort.reverse`. A small experiment: `n=10**6; a = (0..n).to_a.reverse; puts a.shuffle.max(a.size) == a #=> true`. Similar for `min`, `min_by` and `max_by`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

For max:

```
arr.sort_by { |el| [-el[0], -el[1]] }
=> [[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

For min:

```
arr.sort_by { |el| [el[0], el[1]] }
=> [[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```