# How to use sort_link with model instance method in rails 4 with Ransack Gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, ransack

I have used Ransack Gem,Rails 4.

**roles_controllers.rb**

```
def index
  @q = Role.ransack(params[:q])
  @roles = @q.result(distinct: true)
end
```

**This is instance method in model(role.rb)**

```
  def user_count
    self.users.count
  end
```

**This is my html table header(Roles/index.html.erb)**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-framed rb-usr-tbl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :name) %></th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q,:role_users_user_count) %></th>
      <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="role-index">
     <% @roles.each do |role| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= role.human_role %></td>
          <td><%= role.description %></td>
          <td><%= role.user_count %></td>

          <td>
            <%= link_to edit_role_path(role), :remote => true,:title => "Edit Role" do %>
                <i class="icon-pencil7 rb-pencil"></i>
            <% end %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to role, method: :delete,:title => "Delete Role", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
                <i class="icon-trash rb-trash"></i>
            <% end %>
          </td>

        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

There is relationship between user and role are One role has_many users.

**Here i want to sort this count of users in asc and desc order but with this code it does not work.**

Help me if you can.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also paste the code of your index method from roles controller?

Comment: Here i have uploaded code of controller and view. please check and let me know solution if you have.

Comment: @Surya : Do you have the answer of the question?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Sorting-in-the-Controller I am suspecting that you have user_id column in roles, then you might have to change the query of ransack accordingly. Try setting a counter cache in roles table for users then use users_count for sorting as mentioned in link.

Comment: @Surya : There is role_id in users table. Your given link is different than what i am asking.First Understand my question then gives answer plz.

Comment: i found this article but in desc order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642182/sorting-an-array-in-descending-order-in-ruby

Comment: @youngdero : this link is not helpful for my question.

Answer (score -2):

Ransack is very smart itself, try to change line

```
<th><%= sort_link(@q,:role_users_user_count) %></th>
```

to

```
<th><%= sort_link(@q, :users_count) %></th>
```

Explanation: In the variable `@q` you keep a Ransack query object on the model `Role`, if you call `sort_link` on `@q` it will apply `users_count` as "join users relation and order by users count".