# Longest word test from appacademy practice in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do this test and there are bunch of solutions online and here but  I first want to figure out why my solution is wrong even though it seems that it puts right results when I enter certain strings :

Here is what they are asking :

> Write a method that takes in a string. Return the longest word in the
>   string. You may assume that the string contains only letters and
>   spaces.
>
> You may use the String `split` method to aid you in your quest.

Here is my solution where I thought I could turn string into array, sort it from max length descending and then just print first element in that new string like this :

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence = sentence.split

  sentence.sort_by! { |longest| -longest.length }

  return sentence[0]
end
```

That doesn't seem to work obviously since their test gives me all false..here is the test :

```
puts("\nTests for #longest_word")
puts("===============================================")
    puts(
      'longest_word("short longest") == "longest": ' +
      (longest_word('short longest') == 'longest').to_s
    )
    puts(
      'longest_word("one") == "one": ' +
      (longest_word('one') == 'one').to_s
    )
    puts(
      'longest_word("abc def abcde") == "abcde": ' +
      (longest_word('abc def abcde') == 'abcde').to_s
    )
puts("===============================================")
```

So the question is why? And can I just fix my code or the idea is all wrong and I need to do it completely different?

Comment: Works for me. All true.

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/fhic6v)   When I put my code in their editor i get all false. And when I put their code i get all true   [link](http://prntscr.com/fhictz)

Comment: Try in your local ruby. https://pastebin.com/natDcvRN

Comment: oh...it does actually work in my ruby. I guess theirs is not good. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `-longest.length` to reverse the sort. Instead, rely on the `reverse` method, which will [outrun all other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651028/128421) except `reverse!`.

Comment: Can I enter somewhere in this line reverse instead of - sentence.sort_by! { |longest| -longest.length } ? Or it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Which word in this string is longest?"

r = /[[:alpha:]]+/
str.scan(r).max_by(&:length)
  #=> "longest"
```

This regular expression reads, "match one or more characters". The outer brackets constitute a *character class*, meaning one of the characters within the brackets must be matched.

To deal with words that are hyphenated or contain single quotes, the following is an imperfect modification<sup>1</sup>:

```
str = "Who said that chicken is finger-licken' good?"

r = /[[[:alpha:]]'-]+/
str.scan(r).max_by(&:length)
  #=> "finger-licken'"
```

This regular expression reads, "match one or more characters that are a letter, apostrophe or hyphen". The outer brackets constitute a *character class*, meaning one of the characters within the brackets must be matched.

<sup>1 I've successfully used "finger-licken'" in scrabble.</sup>

Comment: "finger-licken"? Must have been some home-grown rules because "-licken" isn't allowed.

Answer (score -1):

I'd write it something like:

```
str = "Write a method that takes in a string"
str.split.sort_by(&:length).last # => "string"
```

Comment: Why not just `last`?

Comment: `last` would work too. I was keying off the OP's use of `-longest.length` to reverse the array, which isn't the fastest.