# ruby - Order a group_by collection desc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of products users have purchased, grouped by their name, so I can count the number of unique products and how many of each has been purchased:

Controller:

```
@line_items = Spree::LineItem.joins(:order).where(spree_orders: {state: "complete"})
@products = @line_items.group_by(&:name)
```

View:

```
<% @products.each do |name, line_items| %>
     <%= name %> - <%= line_items.count %><br>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to order the `.each` loop so that it descends by `line_items.count`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It will perform better getting the correct data directly from the db:

```
@products = @line_items.group(:name).order("count_all DESC").count
```

That will give you the names and counts directly, e.g.

```
# => { "line_1" => 3, "line_2" => 2, "line_3" => 8 }
```

There's a bit of Rails magic at work here: the SQL generated using `group`, `order` and `count` will look like:

> `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM spree_line_items GROUP BY name ORDER BY count_all DESC`

That's where `count_all` comes from: Rails attaches it to the count column automatically.

Then you can plug this directly into your view:

```
<% @products.each do |name, line_item_count| %>
  <%= name %> - <%= line_item_count %><br>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, if you're using the instance variable elsewhere, here's a simple Ruby solution:

```
@products = @line_items.group_by(&:name).sort_by { |_k, line_items| line_items.count }.reverse
```

This simply uses [`sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) to get records ordered by the relevant count, then reverses to get decending order. There's a good benchmark on doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651028/4055042).

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on / if you've any questions.

Comment: Did this help at all @Alex?