# How to sort array or hash including hash in rails?

Tags: ruby

I am new to rails. how to sort total leads in my array of hash. total leads maximum values should be first.

```
Array  = [
  {
    "project_name"=>"Godrej United",
    "lead_stats"=>{ 
       "total_leads"=>1, 
       "untouched_leads"=>0, 
       "dumped_leads"=>1, 
       "not_responding"=>0, 
       "switched_off"=>0, 
       "hot_leads"=>1, 
       "cold_leads"=>1, 
       "warm_leads"=>0
     },
     "project_id"=>2
   },
   {
     "project_name"=>"Golden Panorama", 
     "lead_stats"=>{
       "total_leads"=>5, 
       "untouched_leads"=>0, 
       "dumped_leads"=>1, 
       "not_responding"=>0, 
       "switched_off"=>0, 
       "hot_leads"=>0, 
       "cold_leads"=>0, 
       "warm_leads"=>0
     }, 
     "project_id"=>10
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: @Vishal Yes I had your benchmark already from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651028/10522579

Answer (score 1):

You sort array as below,

```
Array.sort_by {|x|x['lead_stats']['total_leads']}.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below,

```
Array.sort_by {|x| -x['lead_stats']['total_leads'] }
```

Alternative for answer is below,

```
Array.sort { |a,b| b['lead_stats']['total_leads'] <=> a['lead_stats']['total_leads'] }
```

Replace `a` and `b` in block to get in reverse order.

Comment: ...or `Array.max_by(Array.size) { ... }`.